# DateTimePicker selection only with DropDown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, datetimepicker

I want to use DateTimePicker in my Form, but I need user to select date only w/ DropDown and I'm trying to disable picking in DateTimePicker itself (e.g. by pressing KeyUp/Down).

```
//this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz_ValueChanged);
this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz.DropDown += dtp_datum_pracVykaz_DropDown;
this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz.CloseUp += dtp_datum_pracVykaz_CloseUp;
```

Where

```
    void dtp_datum_pracVykaz_DropDown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz_ValueChanged);
    }

    void dtp_datum_pracVykaz_CloseUp(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz.ValueChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.dtp_datum_pracVykaz_ValueChanged);
    }
```

The problem is that DTP is enabled, so user can change date without DropDown (but it won't have effect). I want something like DTP.Enabled = False; but icon for DropDown must be enabled.

Comment: That means you want the Dropdown to have a button that will only be active and not the entire Dropdown. In that way the user cannot enter any value. Right ?

Comment: You probabbly misunderstood me. I want the datetimepicker not to be selectable/changable, on the other hand I want the part of the control, which contains icon of dropdown calendar to be active, so user can drop whole calendar and select date over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the keydown event -

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

This way any key pressed by the user will be ignored effectively disabling user keyboard input.

Comment: Thx for input, your solution was usefull for me. :]

Comment: Allthough this functions as a workaround i get the problem of having to click twice somewhere else to activate the functions again in other form items.
I guess it would be best to evualate the value for a valid date in the onchange event.