# DateTimePicker Set DropDownList style in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `DateTimePicker` and I want set read-only not disabled. I do not want to write by hand, only to be able to choose from the calendar.

`ComboBox` has property `DropDownStyle` and I can choose `DropDownList`. I want something like it

Comment: It is fairly unclear what you are asking. Please explain in more detail and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @EricSchaefer I want selection only with DropDown like selection from combo box dropdownlist mode

Answer (score 1):

I think using the keydown event like mentionned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15878148/8147103) resolves your problem.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: ComboBox has property DropDownStyle and I can choose DropDownList. I want something like it

Comment: @Beso would you post an image illustration with feature that you want to have by editing your question please ?